# Filter SharePoint library items by lookup column using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list and a document library. Each document is linked to an item in my list using a custom field CustomRecordLookupId

If I select all documents and use $expand=listitem, I can see the CustomRecordLookupId values in the results.

I am unable to use this lookup column to query, however.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root/children?$expand=listitem&$filter=listitem/fields/CustomRecordLookupId eq 1
```

The error is: `Operation not supported`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, I got the same result as yours. This is not supported for drive item, you should do the filter for listitems:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/CustomRecordLookupId eq 1
```

Comment: That will not return anything from the document library. I need to filter all documents to just those for CustomRecordLookupId = 1

Comment: You could expand driveitem property in the endpoint, like this:$expand=fields,driveitem&$filter=fields/CustomRecordLookupId eq 1

Comment: I did not realise you can query a library using the list endpoint. Very helpful, thanks.